# Posix awk escaping in sub()

Tags: awk

What is the posix awk compliant result of this awk program (if any?), and why do mawk and goawk not agree with gawk and onetrueawk?

```
BEGIN { a = "a"; sub("a", "-\\\\a-", a); print a; }
```

```bash
$ mawk -f prog.awk                                         Mon Jan  9 20:12:52 2023
-\a-
$ goawk -f prog.awk                                        Mon Jan  9 20:13:02 2023
-\a-
$ gawk -f prog.awk                                         Mon Jan  9 20:12:58 2023
-\\a-
$ onetrueawk -f prog.awk                                   Mon Jan  9 20:12:59 2023
-\\a-
```

Note that the above program is copied from a file and not run through any escaping my shell might do.

Comment: I ran across similar issue while using backslashes for passing field separator via the `-F` option. I managed to find a rule that works consistently for both `mawk` and `gawk` - "use 4 backslashes for every backslash" or use "`\x5c\x5c` for every backslash" (see [my blog post](https://learnbyexample.github.io/escaping-madness-awk-literal-field-separator/) for details). That rule isn't working when I tried with your `sub()` example :-/

Comment: Using `gawk --posix` is working for your example. See if `onetrueawk` also offers such an option?

Comment: @Sundeep from your post I found this which clarifies: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gory-Details looks like gawk briefly had posix behavior then reverted. That answers my Q.

Comment: @EdMorton not sure if I got your point about `-` and `]` correctly. If I use `echo 'a-b' | awk -F'[-]' '{print $1}'` and `echo 'a]b' | awk -F'[]]' '{print $1}'`, I get the expected results for both gawk and mawk.

Comment: @nlta feel free to add an answer with the relevant quote from the gawk manual that helped answer your question.

Comment: @EdMorton I think you missed the context. The problem statement is given an input, generate string that will help to split fields based on the input considered literally. So, if user wants to split on `a.b\c^d`, I'm using the commands presented in that article to get `[a][.][b]\\\\[c]\\^[d]` which will then be used as `awk -F'[a][.][b]\\\\[c]\\^[d]'`

Comment: @Sundeep : side note - for the love of Shiva Buddha Allah God and Jehovah, don't use so called `onetrueawk` ::::::: `echo 3 | nawk '$++NF = exp()'` =====>  `3 20.0855` ::::::::::::::::::::::::: it's even willing to return results on entirely empty inputs for exponential function

Comment: @EdMorton not sure how that is wrong. `[-]` will match `-` literally, `[]]` will match `]` literally and so on. But using `[\]` or `[^]` will give error. These are all applied on individual characters, so there is no possibility of something like `[X-]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior exhibited by gawk is non-posix. If you run gawk with `gawk --posix -f prog.awk` you see the posix behavior expected: the string is first unescaped lexically and then unescaped again when parsed as an ERE arg to sub.

```bash
$ gawk --posix -f prog.awk
-\a-
```

Gawk briefly tried to standardize on the posix behavior in 4.0.0 but this broke backwards compatibility and was quickly reverted. [Source: the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gory-Details)